# Error using excel vba sendkeys to paste data correctly then place and end automation on a different active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I have been working on some VBA code to open firefox, send the necessary keystrokes to get me the data (the weather at a specific time), and paste it into my spreadsheet.
The links are all generated using excel cell formulas using the data I input from my worksheets.
I am sure it isn't the most efficient code but everything works except I want to paste into a specific cell on sheet2 where all my formula lines are and before the code is finished return me to sheet1 where the output data is.
See in the code the last steps are to activate sheet2, send control-v, and activate sheet1... what happens is that it sends the command, activates sheet1 then it actually fills whichever cell is selected.
I've tried reading a lot of forums, using other pasting methods, separating modules further, and breaking up the sequence by doing something like even opening another program all to no avail.
How do I return to sheet1 AFTER the sendkeys "(^v") function is completed?
Link example I would be using. It likely won't work if after the date within it but adjusting the date and it will work.
wunderground.com/hourly/us/ma/easthampton/01027/date/2021-11-12
Hopefully this is an easy solution and any help is greatly appreciated, thank you so much in advance

```
    VBA.Shell "explorer.exe C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\firefox.lnk", vbNormalFocus
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E19").Copy ‘URL location
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02") 
SendKeys "^v", True
SendKeys "~", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10") ‘Webpage Load Delay
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
str1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B80") 
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B80").Copy ‘Time-to-search-for location (example “10:00 AM”)
AppActivate "firefox", True
SendKeys "^f", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
SendKeys "^v", False
If str1 = "2:00 PM" Then
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}"), True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}"), True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    SendKeys ("{enter}"), True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    SendKeys ("+{TAB}"), True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    SendKeys ("+{TAB}"), True
End If
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
SendKeys ("+{TAB}"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
SendKeys ("+{DOWN}"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
For t1 = 1 To 3
    SendKeys ("+^{LEFT}"), True
Next t1
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
SendKeys ("^c"), True
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
ActiveSheet.Range("E70").Select
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
SendKeys "^v"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that `SendKeys` is going to work how you want. There are much better ways to do this. Why are you using `SendKeys`?

Comment: It will be better if you can explain your end goal so that we can suggest proper solution. As braX said, `SendKeys` (and activating app back and forth) is highly unreliable.

Comment: You can remove everything after the line `AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"` and just add the code `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").paste`  or change A1 to which ever the cell you want to paste into

Comment: I want to use VBA automation to ultimately work between multiple programs.

Comment: I am supposed to get job information from an inconsistently filled out form online which I copy manually into excel which finds the lines I need, formats it then I need to get the weather info back to excel which is where my code starts working. Ultimately, I was hoping to copy the data gathered into a third program. I am using sendkeys because I am unsure if it will respond properly to other automated commands and being on the newer side to programming, its the best Ive been able to find so far.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").paste doesnt work. Maybe because what is being copied from firefox is multiple cells when pasting? Tried using that command and specifying the range instead without luck.

Comment: Could I trouble someone to at least point me towards a better path? I google search for the functions to achieve the goals I have, I would love to know where to start learning more efficient and reliable code.  Where should I start?  Thank you everyone for your help thusfar